# How to print a multiline string to a file with variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Data: [redacted]

I'm new to python (only know R) and I'm attempting to do a rather trivial task but can't figure it out.

I'm trying to format a table in python that looks like this:

```
  Financial Analysis
  ----------------------------
  Total Months: 86
  Total: $38382578
  Average  Change: $-2315.12
  Greatest Increase in Profits: Feb-2012 ($1926159)
  Greatest Decrease in Profits: Sep-2013 ($-2196167)
```

I've managed to recreate it with this code:

```
print(f"""
{line1}
{line2}
{line3}
{line4}
{line5}
{line6}
{line7}
""")


Financial Analysis
----------------------------
Total Months: 86
Total: $38382578
Average Change: $-2315.12
Greatest Increase in Profits: Feb-2012 ($1926159)
Greatest Decrease in Profits: Sep-2013 ($-2196167)
```

Full preceding code:

```
#Import data
df = pandas.read_csv('Resources/budget_data.csv')
df.head()

date = df['Date'].count()
sum_profit_losses = df['Profit/Losses'].sum()
avg_change = round(df['Profit/Losses'].diff().mean(),2)
df['change'] = df['Profit/Losses'].diff()
greatest_increase = df.sort_values(by="change", ascending=False).iloc[0,0:3]
greatest_decrease = df.sort_values(by="change").iloc[0,0:3]

line1 = "Financial Analysis".format()
line2 = "----------------------------".format()
line3 = "Total Months: {}".format(date)
line4 = "Total: ${}".format(sum_profit_losses)
line5 = "Average Change: ${}".format(avg_change)
line6 = "Greatest Increase in Profits: {a} (${b})".format(a=greatest_increase["Date"], b=round(greatest_increase["change"])) 
line7 = "Greatest Decrease in Profits: {a} (${b})".format(a=greatest_decrease["Date"], b=round(greatest_decrease["change"])) 

a = print(f"""
{line1}
{line2}
{line3}
{line4}
{line5}
{line6}
{line7}
""")
```

The problem is, the whenever I put my string into print to get a multiline statement, it results as a "NoneType" so whatever method I attempt to use to write it out to a file fails. I have confirmed that each individual variable (line1, line2, etc.) are all str types but once I put this into a print statement it throws everything off due to the "NoneType".

What's the correct way to do this?

Edit: Final Correct Code:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('Resources/budget_data.csv')
date = df['Date'].count()
sum_profit_losses = df['Profit/Losses'].sum()
avg_change = round(df['Profit/Losses'].diff().mean(),2)
df['change'] = df['Profit/Losses'].diff()
greatest_increase = df.nlargest(1, 'change')
greatest_decrease = df.nsmallest(1,'change')
line1 = "Financial Analysis"
line2 = "----------------------------"
line3 = f"Total Months: {date}"
line4 = f"Total: ${date}"
line5 = f"Average Change: ${avg_change}"
line6 = f"Greatest Increase in Profits: {greatest_increase['Date'].item()} ${round(greatest_increase['change'].item())}"
line7 = f"Greatest Decrease in Profits: {greatest_decrease['Date'].item()} ${round(greatest_decrease['change'].item())}"
s = f"""
{line1}
{line2}
{line3}
{line4}
{line5}
{line6}
{line7}
"""
print(s)
with open("output.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(s)

Financial Analysis
----------------------------
Total Months: 86
Total: $86
Average Change: $-2315.12
Greatest Increase in Profits: Feb-2012 $1926159
Greatest Decrease in Profits: Sep-2013 $-2196167
```

Comment: Please show your actual code, not just bits and pieces out of order.

Comment: Since you apparently know host to use f-strings, why are you still bothering with `.format()`?

Comment: `print()` doesn't return the string, it just prints it. If you want to write the string to a file, assign the string to a variable and call `f.write(variable)`

Comment: You can also use the `file` argument to `print()`: `print(f""" ... """, file=f)`

Comment: I am not sure where your NoneType (error?) is coming from -- it doesn't seem to be from anything you have shared. If you'd like to write to a file: `with open("abc.txt", "w") as f: f.write(string_to_output)`

Comment: @Barmar I've included the full code. I see your comment about "why bother with .format()" and it's because this is my first ever python script so if some things look weird/redundant it's because I'm a bumbling baby.

Comment: @ELinda the NoneType error arises when when I wrap my variables in the print() function. It's not explicitly included there for brevity but I came to this conclusion with type(a) which outputs "NoneType".

Comment: Got it, then it is because `print` doesn't return anything. In Python -- Programmer's answer below can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`print(...)` returns `None`. Assign your multiline f-string to a variable, which you then can print out to the console *and* write it to a file:

```py
date = df['Date'].count()

line1 = "Financial Analysis"
line2 = "----------------------------"
line3 = f"Total Months: {date}"

s = f"""
{line1}
{line2}
{line3}
""")
print(s)
with open("some/file.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
total_month = 86
total = 38382578
average_change = -2315.12
greatest_increase_in_profits = 1926159
greatest_decrease_in_profits = -2196167

string = """Financial Analysis
  ----------------------------
  Total Months: {0}
  Total: ${1}
  Average  Change: ${2}
  Greatest Increase in Profits: Feb-2012 (${3})
  Greatest Decrease in Profits: Sep-2013 (${4})""".format(total_month, total, average_change, greatest_increase_in_profits, greatest_decrease_in_profits)
print(string)
```

Output:

```
Financial Analysis
  ----------------------------
  Total Months: 86
  Total: $38382578
  Average  Change: $-2315.12
  Greatest Increase in Profits: Feb-2012 ($1926159)
  Greatest Decrease in Profits: Sep-2013 ($-2196167)
```

Comment: He's using triple quotes already, see the first `print()` call in the question.

Comment: My question isn't about creating the table, I have figured out that part. Its writing it out to a file.